# Does this sequence of functions defined on a closed disk have a pointwise limit?

Tags: functions

Let $f_n(z)=(-1^n)z^n.$ Does $(f_n)$ have a pointwise limit in the closed unit disc?

I am unsure on how to approach this at all so help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: So what happened when you tried $z=1/2, z=1,$ and other values?

Comment: I guess at z=1 the series diverges but at z=1/2, then series converges to 0?

Comment: It's a sequence, not a series. But let me ask: what happens if $z=.999924 i?$

Comment: I am unsure unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$f_n (1) = (-1)^n\longrightarrow?? \text{ as } n\longrightarrow \infty$$

Comment: I think the answer is -1? Sorry, this topic confuses me.

Comment: If the answer is $-1$, then as $n$ goes large, $(-1)^n$ will get very close to $-1$. Say $| (-1)^n - 1 | < 0.00001$. Is that possible?

Comment: No, it is not. I understand this concept, I'm just unsure on how to prove it for all cases of z